# How to check array contains string by using pyspark with this structure

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

The curly brackets are odd. Tried with different approaches, but none of them works

```
# root
#  |-- L: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- S: string (nullable = true)

# +------------------+
# |                 L|
# +------------------+
# |[{string1}]|
# |[{string2}]|
# +------------------+
```

Comment: Can you expand on your question a bit? Which array should contain what? The array from inside of each row of your dataframe? Or an external array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [filter()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.filter.html) to get array elements matching given criteria.

Since, the elements of array are of type struct, use [getField()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.getField.html) to read the string type field, and then use [contains()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.contains.html) to check if the string contains the search term.

Following sample example searches term "hello":

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[[[("hello world",)]],[[("foo bar",)]]], schema="L array<struct<S string>>")

string_to_search = "hello"

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn("arr_contains_str", \
                   F.size( \
                          F.filter("L", \
                                   lambda e: e.getField("S") \
                                              .contains(string_to_search))) > 0)

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---------------+----------------+
|L              |arr_contains_str|
+---------------+----------------+
|[{hello world}]|true            |
|[{foo bar}]    |false           |
+---------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you! I find I can also do something like record["L"][0]["S"] to get the data

Comment: Yes, you can do `df = df.withColumn("arr_contains_str", df["L"][0]["S"].contains("hello"))` if you always have only one element in the array (singleton).